# Unity: Change UI gameObject parent and position without moving Child gameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, unity-ui

I have a UI in Unity where I constantly move items from one place to another.

Some of said items are containers, and I decided to give each containers their own child gameObject representing and containing the actual container's content once opened (aka activated the gameObject). I chose to do it this way to be easier to track each container's actual containers.

What I want: When changing the item's parent (aka moving it around since all my parents have layout groups), the child gameObject should remain at the same world position

What I have: When changing the item's parent, the child gameObject changes world position

What I can do: I could reset the position of the child gameObject each time, as I do the first time the gameObject is instantiated using this code (the relative gameObject is stretched)

```
Vector3[] corners = new Vector3[4];
transform.parent.parent.GetComponent<RectTransform>().GetWorldCorners(corners);
float width = corners[2].x - corners[0].x;
float height = corners[1].y - corners[0].y;
RectTransform itemTransform = item.transform.GetChild(1).GetComponent<RectTransform>();
itemTransform.position = new Vector3(width / 2, height / 2);
```

What I want to know: Is there something built in Monobehavior or Unity that prevents a child gameObject from moving

Here are images step by step of one of the cases it would apply:
[image: Here I have a bag called "sac a dos in my room]

Here I have a bag item called "sac a dos" in my room

[image: Now I have opened The bag, which shows up in the middle of the screen]

Now I have opened The bag, which shows up in the middle of the screen

[image: I now have created a chest item called "Coffre" at the same place, causing the bag to be put as child of the chest's container child gameObject]

I now have created a chest item called "Coffre" at the same place, causing the bag to be put as child of the chest's container child gameObject

[image: Here I opened the chest, showing the bag that was put as child of the chest's container child gameObject, and positioned at the right place]

Here I opened the chest, positioned at the right place, and showing the bag that was put as child of the chest's container child gameObject

[image: Here I opened the bag in the chest, causing the bag's child gameObject to be misplaced since the bag's position changed]

Here I opened the bag in the chest, causing the bag's child gameObject to be misplaced since the bag's position changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You should separate items data from their display.

When You have a common display of your elements write a Show method, where you could pass showed item data.

Example:

```
public class ItemDisplay : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Show(ItemData itemData)
    {
        this.gameObject.SetActive(true);

        foreach (var property in itemData.properties)
        {
            DisplayProperty(property);
        }
    }

    private void DisplayProperty(){...}
}
```